# Lognormal standardisation

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution

Suppose we have a standardized normal $Z_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and take the associated lognormal $X = e^{Z_1}$.

Suppose that with have a non-standardized normal $Z_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and the associated lognormal $Y = e^{Z_2}$

Is there somewhere an expression in terms of $\mu,\sigma$ for standardisation parameters $a,b \in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_{+}$ such that, **in distribution**,

$$Y = aX+b \text{ ?}$$

Comment: $Y=e^{Z_n} => Y = e^{aZ_1+b} => Y = (e^{Z_1})^a e^b$ what is wrong with this?

Comment: This is not linear. I need a linear transformation.

Comment: An immediate implication of @quester's equation is that unless $\sigma=1,$ there exists no such linear transformation.

Comment: it's impossible due to left-side restricted support.... only approximations

Comment: @Quester hints at a neat demonstration of impossibility. When $b\ne 0,$ $aX+b$ either assigns some probability to negative values or fails to assign any probability to small positive values, showing it cannot be lognormal. When $b=0,$ the effect of $a$ is to rescale $X:$ but changing $\mu$ rescales $X$ by $e^\mu.$ Consequently, *$a$ is just a reparameterization of $\mu.$* If you could always find such an $a,$ then $\sigma$ would be superfluous: but we know that's not the case.  This easily shows why you cannot hope to find such an $a$ and $b$ in general; you can only hope for special cases.

Answer (score 2):

**Unless $\sigma=1,$ no such linear transformation exists.**  This is an immediate consequence of the one-to-one correspondence between $\sigma$ and the skewness of a lognormal variable, because linear transformations do not change the magnitude of the skewness and lognormal variables always have positive skewness.

---

Consider the skewness of $Y=\exp(Z_2),$ [given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)

$$\beta_3(Y)= \left(\exp(\sigma^2) + 2\right)\sqrt{\exp(\sigma^2)-1}.$$

The skewness of any variable is the [third moment of its standardized version of the variable.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Pearson's_moment_coefficient_of_skewness)  Because linear transformations with positive slopes do not change the standardization, they leave the skewness unchanged.  Thus, from the two expressions $aX+b=Y=\exp(Z_2)$ and noting $a\gt 0$ we obtain

$$\left(e^1+2\right)\sqrt{e^1-1} = \beta_3(aX+b) = \beta_3(Y) = \left(e^{\sigma^2/2} + 2\right)\sqrt{e^{\sigma^2/2} - 1}.\tag{1}$$

**The claim is that $\sigma=1$ is the only (positive) solution to this equation.**  To see why that is so, for $t\gt 0$ define

$$f(t) = \sqrt{t(t+3)^2}.$$

Writing $\lambda = \exp(\sigma^2)-1$ and $\rho = \exp(1)-1$ (both of which are positive), equation $(1)$ asserts

$$f(\lambda) = f(\rho).$$

However, as a function defined on the positive numbers, *$f$ is one-to-one.*  This is readily seen by noting that the derivative

$$\frac{d}{dt} t(t+3)^2 = 3(t^2 + 4t + 3)$$

can never be zero for $t\gt 0,$ implying $f^2$ is a positive one-to-one function, whence so is $f.$  Consequently $\lambda=\rho,$ showing that $\sigma=1$ is the only solution.

(On the other hand, when $\sigma=1,$ $Z_2 = Z_1 + \mu$ and therefore

$$Y = \exp(Z_2) = \exp(Z_1+\mu) = e^\mu \exp(Z_1) = e^\mu X + 0$$

indeed is a linear transformation of $X$ with $a=e^\mu,b=0.$)